# Why my character array(string) is breaking?

Tags: c++, string, cout

I have written a code to copy from first string's element to second string except space.it simply takes input and if it gets a space then it doesn't insert character of first string into second string. when i am printing second string at the last,the string is partially broken up. But instead of space,if i put any character the second string fully prints out.I am trying but could you fix my bug please?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char str1[100];
    while(cin>>str1)
    {
        char str2[100];
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0; str1[i]!='\0'; i++)
        {
            if(str1[i]!=' ')
            {
                str2[k] = str1[i];
                k++;    
            }
        }
        str2[k] = '\0';
        cout<<"result is "<<str2<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the string is partially broken up"? What output do you get and what do you expect to get?

Comment: Probably because `cin` doesn't scan spaces.

Comment: `cin >> str1` reads the next word up to a space character, so your error is in how you read the string. You could use `std::getline(cin, str)`, for which `str` has to be a `std::string` or `std::fgets()` from `<cstdio>` if you want to read into a char array.

Comment: Thanks everybody. i used it  while(fgets (str1, 100, stdin)) and it finely works.

Comment: @MOehm there is a `getline` for char arrays too...

Answer (score 1):

You can use gets() and puts() to read/display a string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    char s1[100], s2[100];
    int k=0;
    puts("Insert your string:");
    gets(s1);
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(s1); i++) {
        if (s1[i] != ' ') {
            s2[k]=s1[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    puts(s2);
}
```

Comment: And why is this a good idea with C++? Also `gets` is bad anyway.